# Mongodb $group + array items count

Tags: arrays, mongodb, group-by

I need to $group Mongodb data according field A and the result should contain the **count of field B items** which is array. For example if data looks like:

```
{A: 1, B: [1, 2, 3]}
{A: 1, B: [4, 2]}
{A: 2, B: [1]}
{A: 2, B: [2, 3]}
{A: 2, B: [1, 2, 3]}
```

the result should look like:

```
{A: 1, countB: 5}
{A: 2, countB: 6}
```

I have a solution with $unwind like:

```
[
    {
        $unwind: "$B"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$A",
            "countB": {$sum: 1}
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "A": "$_id.A",
            "countB": "$countB"
        }
    }    
]
```

My question is if it is possible to do it **without $unwind** stage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size) operator to get the length the individual arrays.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$A",
    countB: {
      $sum: {
        $size: "$B"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have you try with aggregation?

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {
"A": "$A",
  count: {
    $size: "$B"
  }
}}])
```

Comment: This query produces an error: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PjPV0XK_WsN

Comment: Sorry, just change $group to $project

Comment: Where is $group?

Comment: @Čamo I already edited it, so you can just use that without any error